# Cómo puedo ver las propiedades/valores de un objeto selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Estoy imprimiendo las propiedades/valores de un objeto de Python de una clase que no hice yo con:

```
print(self.__dict__)
```

y me devuelve:

```
{'_mobile': <selenium.webdriver.remote.mobile.Mobile object at 0x00000000045A6A90>, 
        '_switch_to': <selenium.webdriver.remote.switch_to.SwitchTo object at 0x00000000045A6A20>, 
        '_file_detector': <selenium.webdriver.remote.file_detector.LocalFileDetector object at 0x00000000045A69E8>, 
        'capabilities': {'cssSelectorsEnabled': True, 
        'driverVersion': '1.2.0', 
        'version': '2.1.1', 
        'javascriptEnabled': True, 
        'driverName': 'ghostdriver', 
        'webStorageEnabled': False, 
        'browserName': 'phantomjs', 
        'proxy': {'proxyType': 'direct'}, 
        'databaseEnabled': False, 
        'nativeEvents': True, 
        'browserConnectionEnabled': False, 
        'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87', 
        'rotatable': False, 
        'applicationCacheEnabled': False, 'handlesAlerts': False, 
        'platform': 
        'windows-7-32bit', 
        'takesScreenshot': True, 'acceptSslCerts': False, 
        'locationContextEnabled': False}, 
        'command_executor': <selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection.RemoteConnection object at 0x000000000353C9B0>, 
        'session_id': 'c5f03c30-6318-11e7-8aa6-9799de3a66bd', '_is_remote': False, 
        'service': <selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service.Service object at 0x000000000353C198>, 
        'error_handler': <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x00000000045A62E8>, 
'w3c': False}
```

Quiero ver los valores/atributos del objeto en la propiedad `error_handler`, para ver si hay algún código de error o algo. ¿Cómo puedo verlo?

Answer (score 2):

Dado que el atributo especial `__dict__` es simplemente un diccionario, puedes usar la clave para acceder a la instancia del atributo:

```
self.__dict__['error_handler'].__dict__
```

o:

```
vars(vars(self)['error_handler'])
```

Un ejemplo simple:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instancia_de_b =  B()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.atributo1 = 0
        self.atributo2 = 'Hola'
```

**Salida:**

> >>> instancia = A()
>   >>> print(vars(vars(instancia)['instancia_de_b']))
>   {'atributo1': 0, 'atributo2': 'Hola'}
>   >>> print(instancia.__dict__['instancia_de_b'].__dict__)
>   {'atributo1': 0, 'atributo2': 'Hola'}

**Nota:** desconozco el funcionamiento de Selenium, la respuesta te permite hacer lo que quieres (acceder a los atributos de la instancia `selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler`) pero por lo que comenta @César en su respuesta es podible que esto no se lo más adecuado para lo que quieres conseguir, dada la finalidad de esta clase.

Comment: Es cierto, a mí me parece, por lo que entiendo de la pregunta, que el tema iba por el lado de conocer el tipo de error. Tu respuesta es la más acertada de acuerdo a lo preguntado por el OP. Saludos!

Comment: @César eso es lo que he entendido yo también, pero como digo no he usado Selenium antes por lo que no se absolutamente nada de como trata las excepciones por lo que me he limitado ha contestar literalmente a la pregunta de una forma un poco kamikaze :). No obstante me parece una forma extraña de hacer esto, despues de ver tu respuesta y de mirar el código fuente de la clase no se si será de mucha utilidad aceder a los atributos de `ErrorHandler` ...

Comment: Me devuelve un diccionario vacío, será problema del script? Yo antes de probar la linea que me dijiste tu habia probado con self.error_handler.__dict__ y me devolvia lo mismo

Answer (score 2):

La clase `selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler` solo se encarga de gestionar el tipo de error que ha sido levantado por el `WebDriver`. Esto lo hace evaluando el tipo de [`ErrorCode`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorCode):

```
class ErrorHandler(object):
    """
    Handles errors returned by the WebDriver server.
    """
    def check_response(self, response):
        # ...
        exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        # etc.
        # ...
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Las excepciones usadas por Selenium se encuentran en [`selenium.common.exceptions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/common/exceptions.html) y si le das una ojeada, todas heredan del `WebDriverException` que ya implementa el método `__str__`:

```
class WebDriverException(Exception):
    """
    Base webdriver exception.
    """

    def __init__(self, msg=None, screen=None, stacktrace=None):
        self.msg = msg
        self.screen = screen
        self.stacktrace = stacktrace

    def __str__(self):
        exception_msg = "Message: %s\n" % self.msg
        if self.screen is not None:
            exception_msg += "Screenshot: available via screen\n"
        if self.stacktrace is not None:
            stacktrace = "\n".join(self.stacktrace)
            exception_msg += "Stacktrace:\n%s" % stacktrace
        return exception_msg
```

Por esta razón, si lo que quieres es conocer el mensaje solo bastaría usar un bloque try / except:

```
try:
    # ...
except Exception, e:
    print e
```